# How to work with gradle wrapper, init script, multi project and best with idea

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

to sum up the components and environment:

- multi-project, typically each gradle project is soley in a seperate git

  - you don't want to use submodules
- [gradle init scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) in a seperate config / super repository
- using [gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)
- for the GUI guy: IntelliJ IDEa with [Gradle integratiom](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/x/YRptAg) -> [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gradle-2.html)
- allowed to use [gradle idea](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.intellij) -> [guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html)

so,

*Q*: **How to elegant marriage these components. How can I define an init script to be used in the wrapper of a single repository without affecting other repositories.**

*I know:*

- init scripts are typical in a "GRADLE_HOME" directory
- init scripts can be defined per console via `-I` 
  (yes, I read the documentation  )

*Problems found:*

- intelliJ doesn't allow to define the `-I` option in UI
- anyone needs to checkout and update a seperate repository if you want to share between projects
- the `settings.gradle` || [`gradle.properties`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html) file seems not to support any option either

*Constraints:*
 (while these are possible answers, they are neither elegant nor fault proof)

- the desired solution should be applicable for SINGLE projects, and should not be globally applied to all projects on the same computer

*Hidden Questions:*

- can I include global gradle settings from an URL so noone needs a clone of the meta-repo??
- does an [URL include](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) do the same as an init script? Or what you can do with initScript what you can't in include?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. **Create a custom gradle distribution** with the common settings defined in the init script
2. Configure your projects to use that distribution through the *distributionUrl* key in the *gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*
3. Use regular gradle build from command line/usual import into intellij - it just works

By the way, there is a [gradle plugin](http://gradle-dist.oss.harmonysoft.tech/) for simplifying custom gradle distribution construction

Comment: unfortunately this seems to be the best of the options - nevertheless it's not that practical due to the fact, that you have an extra asset to maintain plus the fact, that code is typically not in the same repository. Anyway: thanks for the plugin hint!

Comment: Well, all problems in computer science can be solved by another level of abstraction except for the problem of too many layers of abstraction :) I don't quite get your concern about different repositories - you publish custom gradle-dist into a shared location and point to it from *gradle-wrapper.properties* in all projects

Comment: my point is: developing 12factor apps includes that any code that belongs to get this project run and deployed is in the same repository so that it is reproducable from scratch anytime ... yes, it's getting esotheric here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can **use the [buildSrc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html)** customization - depending on what you need -

where `buildSrc/build.gradle` takes effect prior configuration phase of your project.

What you should know, that there is a different scope, i.e. `buildSrc/build.gradle`'s `allprojects` is scoped to any project beneath `buildSrc` and not your normal projects.
More generally speaking: `buildSrc/build.gradle` is like what you do normally in `buildscript` or task declarations in [script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins) and you can write clean [plugin code](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) without publish it as plugins.

⚠️ *Limitations:*

1. you can't take care about plugin resolution - therefor you have to get into your projects `settings.gradle`
2. you can't change dependency management for your projects - you still have to do this in your project's buildSrc

for both you can see [How can the gradle plugin repository be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285413)

3. you still have to apply (even self `buildSrc` homed) plugins in your project (what is a good thing if you ask me, because it's more visible / clear what happens)
4. you can't share this with a second repository - without using git submodules, etc.