# How can the gradle plugin repository be changed?

Tags: gradle, build, gradle-plugin

I work at a big company with a strict policy forbidding the unfiltered use of outside libraries. We have to pull everything from blessed corporate repositories, and not the bare internet, including gradle.org.

Using gradle's original apply plugin syntax, in conjunction with a buildscript block, I can add (blessed) plugins to our repo and use them in builds. In other words:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://privaterepo.myemployer.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        // various dependencies
        classpath "org.something:some-plugin:1.0"
        ...
    }

apply plugin: "someplugin"
```

Instead, I want to be able to use the new plugins DSL, i.e.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.something.some-plugin' version '1.0'
}
```

(I realize that the private repo url would need to be defined somewhere)

The new plugin syntax always goes to gradle.org and does not appear to have any means to provide an alternate download url. Does anyone know of a way?

I've scrutinized the documentation and the Internet and can't find the answer. Apologies if the answer is completely obvious.

Many Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the ability to do exactly this is coming in Gradle 2.14 whose first release candidate should be out this week.

Comment: Heads up. The release candidate was published this morning. http://gradle.org/release-candidate/

Comment: If its have fix for this?

Answer (score 38):

### Gradle 3.5 and (presumably) later

Gradle 3.5 has a new ([incubating](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/feature_lifecycle.html)) feature, allowing finer control of the plugin dependency resolution, [using the `pluginManagement` DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management):

> Plugin resolution rules allow you to modify plugin requests made in
>   `plugins {}` blocks, e.g. changing the requested version or explicitly
>   specifying the implementation artifact coordinates.
>
> To add resolution rules, use the `resolutionStrategy {}` inside the
>   `pluginManagement {}` block:
>
> **Example 27.6. Plugin resolution strategy.**
>
> ```
> settings.gradle
> pluginManagement {
>   resolutionStrategy {
>       eachPlugin {
>           if (requested.id.namespace == 'org.gradle.sample') {
>               useModule('org.gradle.sample:sample-plugins:1.0.0')
>           }
>       }
>   }
>   repositories {
>       maven {
>         url 'maven-repo'
>       }
>       gradlePluginPortal()
>       ivy {
>         url 'ivy-repo'
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This tells Gradle to use the specified plugin implementation artifact
>   instead of using its built-in default mapping from plugin ID to
>   Maven/Ivy coordinates.
>
> The `pluginManagement {}` block may only appear in the **settings.gradle**
>   file, and must be the first block in the file. Custom Maven and Ivy
>   plugin repositories must contain plugin marker artifacts in addition
>   to the artifacts which actually implement the plugin.

The `repositories` block inside `pluginManagement` works the same as the `pluginRepositories` block from previous versions.

---

### Prior to Gradle 3.5

Prior to Gradle 3.5, you had to [define the `pluginRepositories` block](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories) in your **settings.gradle**, as explained in sytolk's answer:

> The pluginRepositories {} block may only appear in the settings.gradle
>   file, and must be the first block in the file.
>
> ```
> pluginRepositories {
>   maven {
>     url 'maven-repo'
>   }
>   gradlePluginPortal()
>   ivy {
>     url 'ivy-repo'
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: is there no way to do this in build.gradle?

Answer (score 13):

The plugin syntax has changed a bit since the latest version of Gradle, and the correct syntax for Gradle 4.x is now:

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
      maven {
        url 'maven-repo'
      }
      gradlePluginPortal()
      ivy {
        url 'ivy-repo'
      }
  }
}
```

So, for example, this **settings.gradle** would use your internal Nexus mirror:

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'https://internal.repo.corporate/repository/gradle-proxy/'
    }
  }
}

rootProject.name = 'My Project Name'
```

More information can be found in [the Gradle plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management).

Answer (score 9):

To apply the setting globally, it can be [added to USER_HOME/.gradle/init.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management) as follows:

```
allprojects {       
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/maven-repo" }
    }       
}   

settingsEvaluated { settings ->
    settings.pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            maven { url "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/maven-repo" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Failed for flutter-plugin, for example, `apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"` did still try to download the `gradle-3-2-1.jar` file; but extending that plugin's `flutter.gradle` file like `buildscript { repositories { maven { url uri(offlineRepoDir) } } }` works ???

Comment: User-level configs should be used for _preferential_ settings (as a general rule, not just for Gradle). Critical configs like this should be stored with the project.

Comment: For those who needs to solve this with KotlinScript DSL, see the discussion at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11885

Answer (score 2):

It`s need to define pluginRepositories in settings Gradle

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories

The pluginRepositories {} block may only appear in the **settings.gradle** file, and must be **the first block** in the file.

```
pluginRepositories {
  maven {
    url 'maven-repo'
  }
  gradlePluginPortal()
  ivy {
    url 'ivy-repo'
  }
}
```