# Added credentials and now Could not find method pluginRepositories() for arguments

Tags: gradle, closures

I am looking at settings.gradle to make the gradle build work with repos/artifactory in AWS.  This means addings credentials.

in **settings.gradle**:

```
pluginRepositories {

    maven 
    { 
        url = 'https://xxxx/yyy/zzz' 
        credentials { username = 'xxxxx' password = '12121212' }
    }
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
```

Now gradle is failing:

> Could not find method pluginRepositories() for arguments [settings_bhy1jsieezsqdcv1n1mwvzl6l$_run_closure1@68012021] on settings 'adc-ingestion' of
>   type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

Is it looking for a different method with default parameters of $it .   Where do I set that?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52978788/6899896  . The syntax to declare repositories in `settings.gradle` has change. Which verson of Gradle are you using?

Comment: more detailed answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44154346/6899896 : you need to replace `pluginRepositories {...}` by `pluginManagement.repositories {...}` in your `settings.gradle` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle proxy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration)