# How do I add a private repo in the pluginManagement block in gradle.settings?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to setup a gradle 5 project which uses a custom plugin someone developed and is available in my company internal repository.

Until now, we have been importing it using the following approach:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        usr = System.env.usr != null ? System.env.usr : project.ext.properties.usr
        pass = System.env.pass != null ? System.env.pass : project.ext.properties.pass

        privateRepo = {
            name "privateRepo"
            url <url>
            credentials {
                username usr
                password pass
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven (privateRepo)
    }

    dependencies {
        // various dependencies
        classpath "org.something:some-plugin:1.0"
        ...
    }

apply plugin: "someplugin"
```

Just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285413/how-can-the-gradle-plugin-repository-be-changed#44154346).
As far as I understood, this is a deprecated approach, so I would like to use  the `pluginManagement` block gradle.settings (again, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52978788/504331))

The problem is that my repository is private, so I would need to define the user and pass variables.

I tried similar approached inside the `pluginManagement` block in gradle.settings, but I could not get it to work: the `pluginManagement` does not support the `ext` block and the `pluginManagement` has to be the first block in the script, limiting my alternatives.

**Is there anyway I can define the variables so it can be used in the `pluginManagement` block?**

**Disclaimer**: my question is not a duplicated of the linked one because my problem is related to the credentials part, that I am having issues defining the variables and values.

Comment: did you solve it? I face exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Well I just added the def inside the block, not ideal but at least works:

```
pluginManagement {

    def artifactoryUrl = "www.my.artifactory.url"
    def artifactoryUser= "myUser"
    def artifactoryPass= "myPass"

    repositories {
            maven {
                name = "A-MavenGoogle"
                url = uri(
                        "https://$artifactoryUrl/list/maven-google-remote/"
                )
                credentials {
                    username = artifactoryUser
                    password = artifactoryPass
                }
            }
            maven {
                name = "A-MavenCentral"
                url = uri(
                        "https://$artifactoryUrl/list/maven-central-remote/"
                )
                credentials {
                    username = artifactoryUser
                    password = artifactoryPass
                }
            }
     }
}
```