# Gradle plugin with custom group id

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Gradle 6.1

I am having difficulties to use the new plugin configuration mode in Gradle with a custom plugin coming from a custom repository.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://custom")
        }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    java
    idea
    id("com.custom.gradle.plugin.myplugin") version "1.1.0"
}
```

I get this error:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.custom.gradle.plugin.myplugin', version: '1.1.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.custom.gradle.plugin.myplugin:com.custom.gradle.plugin.myplugin:1.1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Gradle will use the plugin id as its group id.

It works if I use the old ways:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://custom")
        }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.custom:com.custom.gradle.plugin.myplugin:1.1.0")
    }
}

apply(plugin = "com.custom.gradle.plugin.myplugin")
```

Is there a way to specify the group id with the 'id' command? Or am I breaking the plugin definition's contract with that old plugin?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the newer/preferred [`plugins { }`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) DSL, the custom plugin must publish a [plugin marker artifact](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers).

If the custom plugin is able to be modified, then I suggest updating to make use of the  [Java Gradle Plugin Development plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html) which will create the marker for you.

If the plugin is not able to be updated, then you can still use the `plugins { }` block, but you'll need to manually resolve the plugin:

In the main `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.custom.gradle.plugin.myplugin") version "1.1.0"
}
```

Then resolve the plugin manually in `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "com.custom.gradle.plugin.myplugin") {
                useModule("com.custom:com.custom.gradle.plugin.myplugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [Plugin Resolution Rules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_resolution_rules)
 for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I guess that, if we want to continue using it, we need to change this indeed.