# Plugin with id com.android.application not found

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, apk

```
apply plugin: 'com.app.roadtonetherlands'
```

and get

> Plugin with id 'com.app.roadtonetherlands' not found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: question title is different to question

Answer (score 0):

This looks like older syntax

Either this non-built-in plugin `com.app.roadtonetherlands` does not exist, or you need to specify where it should be dowloaded from
([How can the gradle plugin repository be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285413/how-can-the-gradle-plugin-repository-be-changed))

New gradle syntax https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html
looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'com.example.hello'
}
```

In any case you need to know where to read docs about this 'com.app.roadtonetherlands' plugin